# LiipImagine bundle doesn't generate thumb

Tags: apache, liipimaginebundle

has anyone ever had a problem with Apache and liip imagine, which makes automatic image generation impossible?

Let me explain, if my server is started via `php -S localhost: 8000 -t public`, liip cannot generate an image, but with `symfony server: start`, yes!

I imagine an Apache config problem? On the other hand, I can generate my images by hand, with the command :

```
bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve ...
```

people who had the same problem say to start the server with :

```
symfony server:start
```

so certainly it works, but on my production environment I am with apache, so I really have to correct the problem (I imagine) in the Apache config
has anyone ever faced this bug?

in VirtualHost or what maybe (I don't know much about it)

Comment: What you mean by `liip cannot generate an image` ? Have you any informations / errors in logs about it (Symfony / php / pache logs  ) ?

Comment: In PHP I have `In PHP I have 127.0.0.1:42512 [404]: GET /media/cache/resolve/photo_bien/img-3-619f6d8537eb3940223094-61d76bfa4f71d911463902.jpg - No such file or directory`

Comment: But I can generate images manually with `bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve image.png`, but it doesn't generate automatically (with Apache, because with Symfony server it's working)

Comment: I found this github issue: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/249 where the issue was similar to you except that it's on nginx server. The issue is definitively related to your apache configuration but I can't do more here since I'm Symfony oriented. I'll edit your question so it's more refered to Apache than Symfony.